# Duplicate code and files between Mobile and Regular site

Tags: mobile, dns, subdomain

I am setting up a mobile site that will be on a subdomain like m.somesite.com. The problem is a lot of the code, plugins, etc... are also required on the mobile site. It almost seems like I am cutting and pasting the site over, and all it has is a new skin...

The problem is since it is a subdomain I can't access code from the main site. What is a good strategy for developing a mobile site that uses a lot of resources from the main site? This just seems so wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `[CSS media queries][1]` You can have different css styles for different sizes for mobile and desktop sites

Comment: It's not just css files, mostly the code in App_Code folder (using .net)